# Where during booting are capabilities retrieved

Tags: setcap

I want a node application to have the ability to bind to low number ports (443 to be precise, since its an http2 server).

I do this with `sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /path/to/node`

This is apparently remembered over a boot.  I am using nvm to allow me to have different versions of node installed, and I have just upgraded the version and of course I no longer bind.

It is easy enough to add the capability again, but presumably somewhere I am accumulating permissions which I ought to switch off on older versions of node.

But I can't find out where in the boot sequence this happens.  Can someone tell me where (I am running Debian).

EDIT

I think the info should be stored within the extra attributes of the executable.  However, I can't find any extra attributes on the files I have set up this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `setcap(8)`, capabilities are set *for the executable file*. This works similar to (but with finer granularity than) SUID or SGID. Nowhere in "the booting process" is this handled; whenever the file is executed as a program, the resulting process gets the capabilities.

Yes, leaving old versions of the file with elevated privileges is a serious security risk, better delete the old versions whenever a new one is installed.

Answer (score 2):

The capabilities are stored with the file entry in the directory (more precisely, they're in the file's [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode), like other kinds of permissions). Nothing special happens during boot.

As of GNU coreutils 8.23, the `ls` command doesn't know about Linux capabilities, so you won't find anything in its output to tell you that a program has capabilities set. Use the `getcap` command to list capabilities.

To clear all capabilities from a file, use `setcap -r /path/to/file`. You don't have anything to clean up, though — the capabilities are stored with the file, there's nothing to do beyond removing the file.